# Laravel PHP - Complex conditional clause in query builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have multiple products saved in a mysql table. It has 2 columns: price and currency. What I want is: given a price range and currency to order the products according to their currency.

Eg.

```
ID-----PRICE---CURRENCY
1-------10-------USD
2-------8-------EURO
3-------43-------CHF
```

I have the following price range: 10 and 18 CHF. I want to convert each one of them to CHF and then order them. Can I do this using Laravel's query builder ?
Could i somehow pass a  function to laravel's where or orderby query builder or something ?

EDIT:

My table looks like

```
ID(int)-----PRICE(int)---CURRENCY(string)-------OTHER COLUMNS
1--------------10-----------'USD'---------------OTHER VALUES
2--------------8------------'EURO'--------------OTHER VALUES
3--------------43-----------'CHF'---------------OTHER VALUES
```

But these are irrelevant now. My current code is:

```
/* Price form and to */
      if($filters->price_start != null && $filters->price_end!= null)
      {
        $query->where('price', '>=' , $filters->price_start)
        ->where('price', '<=', $filters->price_end);
      }
      else if($filters->price_start != null)
      {
        $query->where('price', '>=' , $filters->price_start);
      }
      else if($filters->price_end != null){
        $query->where('price', '<=', $filters->price_end);
      }
```

But it is not taking in mind the currency factor.

EDIT 2:

Something like

```
$query->where('price', '>=', $filters->price_start, function((e)
{ 
   if($this->currency != 'CHF') 
   $this->price = $this->price * rate[$this->currency];
});
```

Comment: If you want to do all of this in MySQL, you'll need a table where you have the currency rate of your main currency and other currencies. You would then join products table with the currency table and multiply the price according to the currency rate in the other table.

Comment: Yeah - I'm not sure you're describing your database well enough. Do you have a products table that just contains the products and then a separate table that contains the prices, which link back to the product table? Or is it one table with multiple entries er product (one for each currency)?

Comment: Just add `$query->where('currency', $filters->currency_code)` kinda thing...?

Comment: I need to get all the products. In pseudocode `$query->where('price', '>=', $filters->price_start, function((e){ if($this->currency != 'CHF') $this->price = $this->price * rate[$this->currency]});`

Comment: Okay now we're getting somewhere - so yes, you won't be able to do this in a nice way in Laravel's query builder only. It requires way too much logic to make it happen in 'raw' SQL, so my suggestion would be to, unless the product table contains tens of thousands of records, just get them all, and then iterate through and apply your logic with `$collection->filter()` or something.

Comment: I know i can do this. But it is not scalable. What if i have millions of records ? Is there any other good way to do this ?

Comment: I'd say the best thing is to not have multiple currencies in your database - normalise them all in some way. Or maybe do a query per currency (how may currencies do you have?)

Comment: If you really want to be able to do it in raw SQL, and your number of currencies is relatively small you can do the following (say the entered currency is CHF): ``SELECT *, IF(`currency` = 'EUR', `currency` * [CHF_EUR_RATE], IF(`currency` = 'USD', `currency` * [CHF_USD_RATE], `currency`)) AS `converted_price` HAVING `converted_price` >= [min] AND `converted_price` <= [max]`` Everything in square brackets being supplied by your PHP code. And obviosuly you'd have to turn that into Query Builder statements (probably using a bunch of `DB::raw()` calls).